# Change number of classes of MNIST Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, mnist, softmax

Hi, Im trying to adapt the beginners tutorial of Tensorflow with MNIST and softmax. In the tutorial you have 10 clases (for digits 0-9).
Now, with a different dataset (EMNIST) I have 62 classes for digits and letters.

What I have in the model of the orginal example is:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b`
```

Where 784 stands for the total pixels of a 28x28 image and 10 is the number of classes. What I want is:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 62]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([62]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b`
```

For 62 classes.

But when I reach this part of the code, where the next batch is called for execution:

```
  for _ in range(1000):
batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

I get this error...
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "calligraphy.py", line 77, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\Willy Barales\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "calligraphy.py", line 64, in main
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
  File "C:\Users\Willy Barales\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Willy Barales\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 975, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 62)'
```

Any ideas on how to change the dataset for this example?
Do I have to change something in the mnist.py file where .next_batch() is implemented?

As far as I know, EMNIST has the exact same format as MNIST. 
Thanks in advance.

Info on the new dataset:
http://biometrics.nist.gov/cs_links/EMNIST/Readme.txt

Comment: yes,  mnist.train.next_batch(100) returns your batch_ys size of (100, 10) and you are expecting it to be (100, 62)

Comment: Well thanks! All I have to do was to edit in the mnist.py file the part where the one hot vectors were created from labeles, since those are the ones corresponding to batch_ys. 
`def extract_labels(f, one_hot=False, num_classes=62)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I have to do was to edit in the mnist.py file the part where the one hot vectors were created from labels, since those are the ones corresponding to batch_ys, thanks to the enlightment of Neijla.

```
def extract_labels(f, one_hot=False, num_classes=62)
```

Besides of course, changing the number of the classes in the model as I stated first in my question.